# HTML pagination

Tags: iphone, html, cocoa-touch, ios, webkit

Is there any opensource project for html pagination?
I am developing an app for iPhone.
I want to display an HTML file on UIWebView and I dont want user to scroll down for seeing the remaining content not being displayed on screen. I want to display the remaining content on the second UIWebView. How can I accomplish this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a little more information about what platform you're using.  Is this an ASP.NET environment, PHP, Ruby, etc.

Comment: What would such a project do? Off the top of my head, I can't think of anything big enough to be considered "a project" that wouldn't be a pluggable module for a specific language (or something narrower such as a framework).

Comment: HTML can't paginate HTML. Ruby can. Perl can. Python can. Haskell can. JavaScript can. Lisp can. [two hours later] Fortran can. Now, can you rethink your question, please? Also, it's usually less than 5 lines of code. (Except in Fortran.)

Comment: pagination as in printing on paper-pages, or pagination as in displaying results on multiple html-pages with navigation buttons?

Answer (score 3):

You could check out the available jQuery plugins:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Here's a demo:

http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

And this is how you use it:

http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/lib/jquery_pagination/README

EDIT: Okay, I posted this before the question was specifically about iPhones and UIWebViews... please don't vote me down :)

Comment: I don't know how the UIWebViews work, I'm not an iPhone developer. But if it has support for standard javascript it should work. However, when you first asked the question you didn't mention anything about having two UIWebViews, why not just make one big so that your content will fit?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery for pagination, it will really make your work simple.