# Make a iOS WebView behave like a ebook reader

Tags: css, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

Normally within a webview, when your page is too long, you can scroll vertically like a browser, that is the default.

I want to make this webview behave like a ebook reader, say when you need 3 pages to display the whole content, instead of scrolling vertically, you can slide to the next page which like a ebook reader (e.g. iOS Kindle app).

Any thoughts on how to implement this? Or any existing components I can use?

Cheer.

Comment: Is the site you present in the web view something you control, or could it be any site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not trivial, and there are a couple of HTML projects having to do with pagination. The ubiquitous jQuery also includes support for paginating HTML content.

Have look at [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397162/html-pagination) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Very much depends on how much control you (want to) have on the html...

For complete layout control (magazine like) there's [baker framework](http://bakerframework.com/).

Or if you need a quick and dirty script auto generate html file with pagination (instapaper like), I'd use [css3 multi-column](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-multicol/) layout, with some js to calculate the column needed. And use something like [SwipeView](http://cubiq.org/swipeview) to manage the scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UISwipeGestureRecognizer on UIWebView and move to the Page programmatically

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you could start with a [`UIPageViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) and populate each page with a `UIWebView`, each scrolled down to a certain offset and disable scrolling of the underlying scroll view.

Comment: Multiple web views offset per page is a terrible idea.

Comment: Agreed it's a hack, but most other solutions involve changing the HTML content, which may or may not be feasible. And only one or two actual web views are needed.